# application stopped when i send sms from application

Tags: android

In my app i want to send message to a mobile which is stored in database. i want to send some message to that number from my application. I have tried some different methods. None worked for me. Kindly check this code and guide me how should i achieve this task

```
    Button sendButton;
EditText msg;

String number;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

    sendButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_message);

     number = getIntent().getExtras().getString("number");


    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            msg.setEnabled(false);
            sendSmS();
        }
    });


}

private void sendSmS() {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String text = msg.getText().toString();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,text,null,null);

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem from the looks of your code it could work?

Comment: I have no idea. when i click on button to send message. Application stops. it is such a headache now

Comment: do you have logcat to post the stacktrace on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you forgot the permission ....

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

in the manifest file? If not, check your values for `number` and `text`. May be they are `null`?

There is nothing wrong else.